# Estrutura de repetição While Python

Tags: python, loop, data, while

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tentando fazer um programa que atualize sempre um mês a minha data: Exemplo tenho uma data minima, data máxima e a data atual quero que sempre que minha data min for menor que a máxima ela some mais um mês até chegar na data atual , ai quando chegar na data atual parar o loop fiz o seguinte código. Obrigado

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Declaração de variaveis
meses = 1
dias_por_mes = 31
data_min = datetime.strptime('2012-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d')   
data_max = datetime.strptime('2019-04-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
hoje = datetime.now()

# Estrutura de repetição
while (data_min < data_max):
    print(data_min)
    data_futura = data_min + timedelta(dias_por_mes*meses)
    print(data_futura)
    if data_min == data_max:
        break
        print('Todos os registros foram inseridos!!!')
```

Comment: Boa tarde Nidorus! Por favor seja mais especifico em onde esta seu problema ou duvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está incrementando variável nenhuma, apenas atribuindo infinitamente `data_futura` com `data_min + timedelta(dias_por_mes*meses)`. Faça assim:

```
data_min = data_min + timedelta(dias_por_mes*meses)
```

Vale ressaltar que nem todos os meses tem 31 dias, com a linha a cima o código só para em `2019-04-15`. Se você quer, de fato, somar sempre um mês a `data_min` uma abordagem mais correta seria através da biblioteca `dateutil` (`pip install python-dateutil`), por exemplo:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
...
data_min = data_min + relativedelta(months = 1)
```

Mas, ainda assim, o código não vai parar na `data_max`, a menos que os dias de ambas as datas sejam idênticos. No seu caso (não parei pra pensar em todos), a seguinte lógica vai funcionar:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Declaração de variaveis
data_min = datetime.strptime('2012-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
data_max = datetime.strptime('2019-04-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
dias = data_max.day - data_min.day
data_max_menos_um_mes = data_max - relativedelta(months = 1)
hoje = datetime.now()

# Estrutura de repetição
while (data_min < data_max):
    data_min = data_min + relativedelta(months = 1)
    if data_min.year == data_max.year and data_min.month == data_max_menos_um_mes.month:
        data_min = data_min + relativedelta(months = 1, days = dias)
        print('Todos os registros foram inseridos!!!')
        break
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, a explicação me ajudou muito